# limit PowerShell commands with authentication policies silos

Tags: powershell

How to limit powershell commands using authentication policies silos?
I wnat to increase security.

I want that, the user can only type a certain and predetermined number of commands in PowerShell. As:
git
composer
php artisan

Comment: Perhaps the conceptual [about_Language_Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Modes) help topic can get you started.